# symfony2 syntax error

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following code:

```
public function postFormAction(Request $request)
{

    $cityId = $request->request->get('shopiousUserBundle_user')['location']['city']; 
    .....
}
```

for some reason this is giving me a syntax error, any idea why?
When I remove the array indexing to be just like:

```
$cityId = $request->request->get('shopiousUserBundle_user')
```

works fine.

Comment: When posting a question that involves any kind of error message, you should **always** add the specific error message to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array dereferencing from the result of a function call is only available in PHP 5.4 or later.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88

If you are using an earlier PHP version, you will have to do the following

```
$data = $request->request->get('shopiousUserBundle_user');
$cityId = $data['location']['city'];
```

Comment: ah.. I thought it was available in 5.3 and above.. thanks a bunch